# Display current page no. and total pages in DocumentViewer?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using DocumentViewer and displaying .xps file in it. Every thing is working fine but when i tried to display the current page and total pages, it didn't work. I tried the DocumentViewerReading_PageViewsChanged event, it's working inappropriately.

by current page no. should be change whenever the page is scrolling, like in Adobe Reader and XPS viewer.

I am using C#/WPF and Visual Studio 2010

following is the code i tried.

```
string strFile = @"data\lib.xps";
xpsDoc = new XpsDocument(strFile, FileAccess.Read);
DocumentViewerReading.Document = xpsDoc.GetFixedDocumentSequence();

///////////////////////////////////

private void txtCurrentPageNo_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (txtCurrentPageNo.Text != "")
    {
        DocumentViewerReading.GoToPage(Convert.ToInt32(txtCurrentPageNo.Text));
    }
}

private void DocumentViewerReading_PageViewsChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtCurrentPageNo.Text = DocumentViewerReading.MasterPageNumber.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this comes years too late but here is your solution. Derive from DocumentViewer and expose the event.

```
public class GenericDocumentViewer : DocumentViewer
{
    public event Action<object> MasterPageNumberChanged;

    protected override void OnMasterPageNumberChanged()
    {
        base.OnMasterPageNumberChanged();
        if (MasterPageNumberChanged != null)
            MasterPageNumberChanged(this);
    }
}
```

I used this (in combination with your above code) to successfully craft a current page display that updates on scrolling.